# aws api gateway validation and authorisation

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-api-gateway, jsonschema

TL;DR  I want to make sure that the userid passed in the HTTP body and the claim subject in the token matches, else its a spoof request

Very interesting scenario , look at this HTTP post request

```
POST /v1/details HTTP/1.1
Host: api.abc.com
Authorization: eyJraWQiOiJwV2FIVXBhXC9NMUZtbXROSTRhblwvTFBxTmhSU1pKRmJKa3NMN2dHWE51bWM9IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.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.V9Gl_xDPx8z4-bd3TDjWTrBo3mVBo9vyYDXOTvMZ-lQRACBvSaK26QOcVCRE1FDJiKBfv4y3ckRGRI3p1T_SnY-rusvfN8rxiRD_kG34W0WF586RpXUGmQ9bL-F7IpVO5Bg1NqlBt3SZjzPWR1xyUxujbs2V-7u6K0dt7Nnv9Tb3H09jYqfwyE6Zu_MqOO9kztFu_SzIXy83pMujE34bVmLTABcJuAFKePDyTRB4tKB_u8ago0VmCnm0ivlivGY8GQsu2tMajA02ihwmXgoX5zDHcyFpYexoY2OtM9m8J62VNgeHjKgkLjlobyC-fL4fG4DbSg42hnEshA2Mz0GYlA
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
{
    "query":"{\n  sprouts_detail(user_id: \"3ae1363d-dce3-4961-bede-ccdfa17c6417\") {\n    sprouts_detail {\n      sprout_id\n   }\n  }  \n}","variables":null,"operationName":null 
}
```

In the header is the cogntio token with user credentials , and the user claims

I can get access to user claims using body templates , like this , but it doesn't seem to work inside model

```
{
    "sub" : "$context.authorizer.claims.sub"
}
```

Question :- I wanted to verify if the $context.authorizer.claims.sub is the same as in the graphql query user_id field in the POST body

```
"query":"{\n  sprouts_detail(user_id: \"3ae1363d-dce3-4961-bede-ccdfa17c6417\")
```

if its same, let it pass through, if its not the same, deny it and throw 403 forbidden

***Not working***

```
{  
   "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "definitions":{  
      "GraphQLAuthorizationModel":{  
         "type":"object",
         "title":"GraphQLAuthorizationModel",
         "properties":{  
            "query":{  
               "oneOf":[  
                  {  
                     "pattern":"$context.authorizer.claims.sub"
                  }
               ],
               "type":"string"
            }
         },
         "required":[  
            "query"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

However if i change $context.authorizer.claims.sub with say user_id , it works as expected and check for the user_id string in the http body payload

Comment: I think we can use request validators, instead of integration request templates. However i am not sure, if we have access to the context object there

Comment: basically , we need to come up with a JSON schema, which can validate the userid from cognitor inside the body of the HTTP request , hope it makes sense

Comment: Why do you want to use JSON Schema to do this? I don't understand the constraints around your question. What language are you using? Is JSON Schema validation something that aws api gateway provides you through an interface or something?

Comment: yes, AWS api gateway provides JSON Schema validation,  JSON Path and VTL out of the box. so that i don't have to code much on the application side, and focus on business logic .

Comment: I tried to create a Model in apigateway, and checked for a patter of string, it worked as expected for hard coded string. when i replaced the hardcoded string in the model with $context.authorizer.claims.sub to make it dynamic for the user, it didn't work :(

Comment: Where does `$context` come from? That isn't a JSON Schema thing.

Comment: $context is aws thingie. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Comment: $context as per doco should be available inside model , inside the json schema

Comment: Looks like that's to do with mapping, and not to do with validation. Where does it say it's available inside the json schema?

Comment: in that link,  Amazon API Gateway defines a set of variables and functions for working with models and mapping templates. This document describes those functions and provides examples for working with input payloads.  Models are implicit JSON schema

Comment: when i am using inside templates, for doing transformations, its working perfectly, but thats at the integration request / response layer, not in the request layer

Comment: Specifically where in that document does it say you can use those variables in the JSON Schema? I don't see any examples of this in that document. It only seems to allow accessing them in the mapping templates. The "API Gateway Mapping Template Reference" defines the variables, which is separate to the validation.

Comment: Amazon API Gateway defines a set of variables and functions for working with models    -- doesnt that say that we can use them inside our model definitions

Comment: You have got a very good point , https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html#models-mappings-models  this links is more description that it confirm to JSONschema- draft4 , which is fair enough. Next question is how can we validate it

Comment: You can't achieve this using JSON Schema. Sorry.

Comment: If you'd like to discuss more, please join me on the JSON Schema slack, which can be found on the json schema site.